# wp-login white screen, narrowed to one plugin but can't get information about the error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a couple sites that are all using Custom Content Type Manager, which is a plugin that has apparently been discontinued and can't be found in the plugin repository.  My problem is that if I go to wp-login.php and log in, I'm directed to a white screen.

If, after seeing this white screen I directly visit /wp-admin/, I'm logged in, so I'm assuming it's an issue with output being generated before the redirect can occur.

If I disable Custom Content Type Manager, I can log in and everything works fine, however, if I try to enable it again, WordPress spits out the following: "Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error."

I am getting *NO* additional output about this mysterious error.  I have tried the following:

1. Edited my php.ini directly to make sure that error_reporting is "On" and the error level is set to E_ALL
2. Added the following to .htaccess

   ```
   php_flag display_startup_errors on
   php_flag display_errors on
   php_flag html_errors on
   php_flag log_errors on
   ```
3. I've turned on debugging with WordPress

   ```
   define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
   @ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
   ```

I'm getting nothing in the browser, nothing in the error_log in /var/log/apache2, nothing in wp-content/debug.log ....

I've checked and all files are owned by www-data, and owner and group write permissions are on all the files.  What am I missing?  I could probably just move on from this plugin, but I have a lot of data stored in custom content types created by this plugin on multiple sites and I think the path of least resistance would be to just make the fixes to the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that particular plugin was [compromised](http://it.slashdot.org/story/16/03/05/0428231/wordpress-plugin-comes-with-a-backdoor-steals-admin-credentials-in-cleartext), chances are this is done deliberately to force you to **remove** the plugin.

Comment: Wow!  That's unfortunate.  Thanks for he link.